# Grey screen for 10 secs after Unity splash screen android build 2018.2.5f1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When building to my android device and launching the build, the Unity splash screen shows and right after goes grey for 10 seconds then my game displays. I tried searching for a solution and couldn't find one. I tried different versions of unity, adding a dummy scene before my scene, and using an android emulator to make sure it is just not my phone. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the file

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">......</application>
```

and at **application** tag find your theme like here with name **AppTheme** now to res>values>style.xml you will file a style tag with the same name like here **AppTheme**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>.....</style>
```

there add this line only at that style tag

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```

after add look like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

    </style>
```

this will resolve issue of gray screen and will give white color also you can use other color if you want to  like this

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">#ffffff</item>
```

here the #ffffff is the color code you can change whatever you want if you need to use image you should first place that image in **res>drawable** folder (better to use small size image only ) and then

```
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/yourimagename</item>
```